# Как изменить некоторые элементы HTML страницы с помощью user-скрипта?

Tags: visual-c++, javascript, html, c++

В общем, проблема в следующем, есть браузерная игрушка(обычное самое простое окно в браузере, без никакого интерактива, только кнопки) для которой я написал программу работающую следующим образом : читает содержимое текстового файла "in.txt", формирует строки с названиями типа "Название.url", запускает лежащие в этой же папке ссылки с такими названиями  с помощью `ShellExecute`.Картинка все поясняет.Код очень корявый, извиняюсь, но вроде работает, открывает, доволен.Но нужно еще следующее, чтобы в открывшихся ссылках, программа заполняла определенное поле (идентификатор `getElementById` которого всегда один)значением считанным из "in.txt" затем нажимала, "Купить", и затем "Да", и так по всем открытым ссылкам.Такое вообще реализуемо? Каким образом можно передать в открытую страницу считанное значение?Реально ли это с помощью user-скриптов?
Прикладываю открывалку ссылок и пару изображений.

[image: img]

```
int main(){
setlocale( LC_ALL,"Russian" );
ifstream I("in.txt");

string str2=".url";
string mass2[15];
string mass3[15];

if(I){

   while( !I.eof() ){
       for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
           getline(I, mass2[i]);
           cout << mass2[i]<<endl;
       }
   }
}
 for(int j=0;j<7;j++){

        if(mass2[j][4] == ' ' && mass2[j][3]==' '){
            mass2[j].erase(0,5);
            cout << mass2[j]<< endl;
        }
        if (mass2[j][3]== ' ' && mass2[j][2]== ' '){
            mass2[j].erase(0,4);
            cout << mass2[j] << endl;
        }
 }
for(int k=0;k<7;k++){
           string S = mass2[k] + str2;
           cout <<S<<" " << k<<endl;
           ShellExecute(NULL, NULL,S.c_str(),NULL,NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT );

}
I.close();
```

}

Знающие люди, направьте на путь истинный. Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Попробуйте передавать параметры через хвост URL (query string? fragment id?)

Comment: Несколько иным образом сформирую вопрос - каким образом можно в открытой ссылке заполнить поле?
Я знаю код элемента этого поля, как его использовать?